# Searching for reddit comment containing any word from list PSAW python

Tags: python, reddit

Hi I'm using [PSAW](https://github.com/dmarx/psaw) and [PRAW](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to fetch reddit comments.

Here is the search code:

```
gen = api.search_comments(subreddit="subreddit1, subreddit2", q="word1, word2")
```

This code checks for comments in subreddit1 and 2 but looks for comments with both word1 and word2. How can i make it so that it searches for comments that contain word1 or word2 or both?

Thanks (let me know if you need any more information)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you cannot do what you're asking in one step, at least not as far as I have seen. But you can certainly do it in multiple steps.

```
# to search for either word1 or word 2, use |
gen1 = api.search_comments(subreddit="subreddit1, subreddit2", q="word1|word2")

# to search for both word1 and word 2, use &
gen2 = api.search_comments(subreddit="subreddit1, subreddit2", q="word1&word2")
```

FYI - Searching for comments in PSAW is essentially a wrapper around

```
api.pushshift.io/reddit/comment/search?q=...
```

and for your question you can play around with that website to get a better understanding of what it will return. The API isnt perfect, you'll still get some comments that contain both words even if you used |, and you'll still get some comments that only contain one of the words even if you used &, but those operators take the bulk of the work off your shoulders.

Comment: When i do gen = api.search_comments does it override the previous search?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, then yes, absolutely. If you were to run my example code exactly as written that would be the case, so sorry for the confusion. As one of the fundamental aspects of programming with variables, every time you assign some result to the variable `gen` it will override the previous thing stored to `gen`. You can get around this pretty easily by either making `gen` be a list and `append` your results to it, or by having multiple variables, like `gen1`, `gen2`, `gen3`, etc. I have changed my post above to go with this 2nd option.

Comment: found this tool, seems to be doing what I need - https://randomtools.io/reddit-comment-search/